# Combine cells value with the header and ignore the blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros, string

I want to combine the fixed row value with diffrent column value but by skipping blank cells. I've a code but it is not working. Please suggest

[image]

```
Public Function SuperJoin(r1 As Range, r2 As Range, IgnoreBlanks As Boolean) As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim s As String

j = r2.Cells.Count
For i = 1 To j
  If IgnoreBlanks = True Then
    If r2.Cells(i) = True Then
        If r2.Cells(i).Value <> "" Then s = s & "-" & r2.Cells(i)
    End If
  Else
    If r2.Cells(i) = True Then
        s = s & "-" & r2.Cells(i)
    End If
  End If
Next

i = r1.Count

For j = 1 To i
    SuperJoin = SuperJoin & "----" & r1(1, j) & r2(1, j)
Next j

SuperJoin = Mid(SuperJoin, 5)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without VBA this ugly formula will do the job.

=IF(ISBLANK(B5),"",B$1&"-"&B5&", ")
&IF(ISBLANK(C5),"",C$1&"-"&C5)
&IF(ISBLANK(D5),"",
(IF(ISBLANK(C5),D$1&"-"&D5,", "&D$1&"-"&D5)))

It is in cell B12 in the screen cap below. Unfortunately, the formula always assumes there are at least two columns with data or it will add a unnecessary , as the results in E show. (Cell B13)

[image]